# Getting an "Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException" error for the program mentioned below

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, do-while

Here it only executes one time and then gives the error given below.
Please help in solving this problem that I'm

```
package project1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class factorial {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String y;
    do {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            
        int flag = 1;
        System.out.println("Print the number:");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
            
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                flag *= i;
        }
        System.out.println(flag);
        System.out.println("Press Y/y to continue");
        y = sc.nextLine();
            
        sc.close();
      } while(y == "Y" || y == "y");
   }
}
```

Output: (Getting an Exception java.util.NoSuchElementException)

```
Print the number:
12
479001600
Press Y/y to continue

y
Print the number:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
   at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
   at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
   at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
   at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
   at project1.factorial.main(factorial.java:14)
```

Comment: when you compare strings then use .equals()

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as follows:

- Change `String y` to `char y`
- And read the char with `y = sc.next().charAt(0)` instead of `nextLine()`

Hope it works

Comment: And change the `while` to `while(y == 'Y' || y == 'y')`